# Dynamic column addition/deletion of DATATABLE in YUI 3.3

Tags: javascript, datatable, yui, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I am working with YUI 3.3 datatable in Liferay. I have a requirement where I need to modify the columns during runtime.  i.e, I need to add few more new columns, or remove few columns from the current COLUMNSET ?
How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

As of YUI3.5, you have access to the Columns attribute:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.html#attr_columns

You may have to monkey patch the datatable to get access to the columns in 3.3: 
[Can you monkey-patch methods of YUI modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281260/can-you-monkey-patch-methods-of-yui-modules)